# convert string into time using vba

Tags: excel, vba

If someone have any solution how can i convert a string to time and find its difference

Suppose in cell(2,1),I have a value in the format 0430_1145,i need to display the difference in cell(2,2) i.e 7.25(7 hours 25 mins)

Comment: Shouldn't that be 7:15?

Comment: yes it should be 7:15

Answer (score 2):

You can use VBA and a few lines:

```vb
Dim TextTime As String
Dim TrueTime As Date
Dim Parts    As Variant

TextTime = "0430_1145"

If TextTime Like "####_####" Then
    Parts = Split(TextTime, "_")
    TrueTime = CDate(CDate(Format(Parts(1), "@@:@@")) - CDate(Format(Parts(0), "@@:@@")))
End If

TrueTime -> 07:15:00
```

Comment: Very elegant! What about to add error handling in case SPLIT() does not work?

Comment: @JohnSUN: That should of course be done. I've included some simple validation of the input value.

Answer (score 1):

`TIMEVALUE(MID(A2, 6, 2) & ":" & RIGHT(A2, 2))-TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A2, 2) & ":" & MID(A2, 3, 2))`

Format cell as time.

Comment: I think you can drop the `TIMEVALUE` since you're doing math on the result. `=(MID(A2, 6, 2) & ":" & RIGHT(A2, 2))-(LEFT(A2, 2) & ":" & MID(A2, 3, 2))`

Comment: Or shorter: `=REPLACE(RIGHT(A2,4),3,,":")-REPLACE(LEFT(A2,4),3,,":")`.